# Github pages does not see CNAME or setup SSL?

Tags: ssl, github, dns, github-pages

I'm deploying an Angular application with this command:

```
ng deploy --base-href=https://fsalpha.fireflysemantics.com --cname=fsalpha.fireflysemantics.com
```

It works and this is the repository it's deployed to:

```
https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fsalpha
```

I have also setup A records so that the CNAME should work.  In other words this url should work:

```
https://fsalpha.fireflysemantics.com
```

However after deploying the SSL checkbox does not enable inside Github Pages and the dialog section for Github Pages looks like this.  Github pages did not picup the CNAME record and place the value in the custom domain field:

[image]

I've tried deleting and recreating the respository, but I'm not having any luck.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this happens when the first commit to `gh-pages` is done by a user with non admin privileges.

As long as the first commit is done by a user with admin privileges, future commits from both non admin and admin users will trigger the build.